# Unable to manually delete an AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use the S3 management console (in Chrome) to delete an S3 bucket. It fails.

[image]
The bucket does have a lot of items in it. I it's about `54.6 TB` (yes, TB..) of data.

Are there any other ways I can delete this bucket? I've got an unsubstantiated feeling I have to do this via CLI (which is fine, but not sure?) and with a server on for a month to delete all of this.

Anyone have any idea's how to delete an S3 bucket of such a large size with a large number of objects?

#### Update

Here's the bucket policy, as requested in the comments:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "<snipped>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<snipped>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<snipped>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your bucket policy. Maybe you have Delete for bucket explicitly denied.

Comment: @JunedAhsan updated OP.

Comment: Can you try deleting the bucket using the AWS CLI? This will be the command
`aws s3 rb s3://bucketname --force`

Comment: The S3 management console also has an **Empty** button. Can you try that first? This will help separate issues about deleting the contents vs deleting the bucket itself. You should also check the permissions you have assigned to you as an IAM User to check that you have enough permission to delete objects and the bucket.

Comment: console does list 1000 objects page so empty bucket deletes only 1000 in first attempt, you need to keep doing it. You can have a iam user with s3 permission and use the script https://github.com/rsavordelli/s3clean/blob/master/s3clean.py

Comment: Another method for emptying a bucket is to create an **Object Lifecycle rule** that expires (deletes) objects older than a given number of days. It will take 24-48 hours to occur, but it can be easier than trying to delete the objects individually.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @John in the comment you can try empty button but before that, your policy does not have permission to delete the object.

```
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<snipped>/*"
```

With the above policy, you can just **Get an object** from s3.

You need to assign delete object or delete bucket permission. you can generate one online [here](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

```
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action":[
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketA/*"
    }
```

Comment: Two questions -> 1) What are values for 'Principal' (with respect to the Policy Generator in the link provided) and 2) Is it possible to make this delete policy only work for me-logged-in ?

Comment: The Principal element specifies the user, account, service, or other entity that is allowed or denied access to a resource. (so you can add your AWS account ID)https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html

Comment: To work this policy only for you, then you need to assign this policy to your user only if you are using common role or policy then create a new policy with above permission and assign that your user only